# Having diffculties in understanding in c code

Tags: c, openvswitch

Sorry, but i am having the following difficulty in a c code.
what is the 3rd line for:

```
#define LIST_FOR_EACH_SAFE(ITER, NEXT, MEMBER, LIST)               \
    for (INIT_CONTAINER(ITER, (LIST)->next, MEMBER);               \
         (&(ITER)->MEMBER != (LIST)                                \
          ? INIT_CONTAINER(NEXT, (ITER)->MEMBER.next, MEMBER), 1   \
          : 0);                                                    \
         (ITER) = (NEXT))
```

The entire code can be found at:
https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/ff261703821658243bba13c80311130d036eeb52/include/openvswitch/list.h

SORRY, but this might take up some time for you to get the entire code.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a function but a macro so you won't see what types different variables have in any declaration. However, at the second row you can see `(LIST)->next` which makes it safe to assume that `LIST` is a pointer to a struct which contains a member called next.

The third row with `&(ITER)->MEMBER != (LIST)` compares this pointer that `LIST` points to with the address of `MEMBER` which is part of a structure that `ITER` points to.

At the fourth row `INIT_CONTAINER(NEXT, (ITER)->MEMBER.next, MEMBER)` is called only if the comparision at row 3 differs. After this call is made `1` is the result which is used to continue the for-loop.

At the fift row you instead get result `0` to end the for-loop if the comparision at row 3 would be equal.

Comment: thank you very much. i guessed the same thing but wasn't sure. thank you